# Is merge without conflicts equivalent to rebase without conflicts?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Is it correct that a `git merge` will succeed with no conflicts if and only if the corresponding `git rebase` will succeed with no conflicts?

Comment: I know it's not exactly what you asked, but do bear in mind that a rebase can potentially result in N successive conflicts (where N is the number of commits to be rebased), whereas there can be only one with a merge.  So there's a significant difference when they *do* conflict :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and in fact there's a trivial case where merge works fine but rebase doesn't:

```
...--o--A   <-- mainline
      \
       B--C--!C   <-- branch
```

where `C` is a commit that conflicts with `A`, and `!C` is its reversion.  Merging `branch` back into `mainline` is equivalent in source-tree effect to merging commit `B` back into mainline, while rebasing copies both `C` (which conflicts with `A`) and then `!C` (which when being resolved, also conflicts with `A`).

Of course, you can rebase interactively and simply drop both `C` and `!C` in this case, but in more complex chains, you can see how a commit might conflict with `A` but a subsequent commit might effectively resolve that conflict "in advance", so that merging the tip of the branch back into the mainline has no conflicts.